# Iterate over Factors in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I am rather new to R and struggling at the moment with a specific issue. I need to iterate over a dataframe with 1 variable returned from a SQL database so that I can ultimately issue additional SQL queries using the information in the 1 variable. I need help understanding how to do this.

Here is what I have

```
> dt
                                   Col
1 5D2D3F03-286E-4643-8F5B-10565608E5F8
2 582771BE-811E-4E45-B770-42A98EB5D7FB
3 4EB4D553-C680-4576-A854-54ED817226B0
4 80D53D5D-80D1-4A60-BD86-C85F6D53390D
5 9EF6CABF-0A4F-4FA9-9FD9-132589CAAC31
```

when trying to access by using it prints the entire list just as above

```
> dt[1]
                               Col
1 5D2D3F03-286E-4643-8F5B-10565608E5F8
2 582771BE-811E-4E45-B770-42A98EB5D7FB
3 4EB4D553-C680-4576-A854-54ED817226B0
4 80D53D5D-80D1-4A60-BD86-C85F6D53390D
5 9EF6CABF-0A4F-4FA9-9FD9-132589CAAC31
```

when trying to access by dt[1,] it brings additional unwanted information.

```
> a<-dt[1,]
> a
[1] 5D2D3F03-286E-4643-8F5B-10565608E5F8
5 Levels: 4EB4D553-C680-4576-A854-54ED817226B0 ... 9EF6CABF-0A4F-4FA9-9FD9-132589CAAC31
```

I need to isolate just the  '5D2D3F03-286E-4643-8F5B-10565608E5F8' information and not the '5 levels......'.

I am sure this is simple, I just can't find it. any help is appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: The column is `factor` class.  Just do `a <- as.character(dt[1,1])` or if it needs to be `factor` then `droplevels(dt[1,1])`

Comment: `a<- as.character(dt[1,])` This is only a fix. If you want to resolve the problem at the source. Make sure your `read.table/read.csv/data.frame/etc whatever` has the option `stringsAsFactors = False`

Comment: @akrun this will get me where I need to be. thank you. post it back as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: @vlo I will try this approach as I am new I don't know what other impacts that this will have but I think longer term this is probably the right answer for what I am doing. I will research it further! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues you need to address.  One is that you want character data, not a factor variable (a factor is essentially a category variable).  The other is that you want a simple vector of the values, not a `data.frame`.

1) To get the first column as a vector, use double-brackets or the `$` notation:

```
a <- dt[[1]]
a <- dt[['Col']]
a <- dt$Col
```

Your notation `dt[1,]` *does* actually return the column as a vector too, but using the somewhat obscure fact that the `[` method for `data.frame` objects will silently "drop" its value to a vector when using the two-index form `dt[i,j]`, but not when using the one-index form `dt[i]`:

> When `[` and `[[` are used with a single vector index (`x[i]` or `x[[i]]`), they index the data frame as if it were a list. In this usage a drop argument is ignored, with a warning.

Think of "dropping" like unboxing the data - instead of getting a `data.frame` with a single column, you're just getting the column data itself.

2) To convert to character data, use one of the suggestions in the comments from @akrun or @Vlo:

```
a <- as.character(dt[[1]])
a <- as.character(dt[['Col']])
a <- as.character(dt$Col)
```

or use the API of whatever you're using to make the SQL query - or to read in the results of the query - not convert the strings to factors in the first place.